# Pandas minute data variable length window finding min value from now to close time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe object with 1 minute data.
Example (say the timestamp is or is not in the index.. either way)

```
timestamp               date        price    endofdaytime
2018-03-11 13:03:00     2018-03-11  20.03   2018-03-11 16:29:52
2018-03-11 13:08:00     2018-03-11  19.00   2018-03-11 16:29:52
2018-03-11 15:22:00     2018-03-11  20.11   2018-03-11 16:29:52
2018-03-11 16:03:00     2018-03-11  21.03   2018-03-11 16:29:52
2018-03-11 16:29:52     2018-03-11  20.03   2018-03-11 16:29:52
2018-03-12 13:03:00     2018-03-12  20.03   2018-03-12 16:29:59
2018-03-12 13:08:00     2018-03-12  19.00   2018-03-12 16:29:59
2018-03-12 16:03:00     2018-03-12  21.03   2018-03-12 16:29:59
2018-03-12 16:29:59     2018-03-12  22.00   2018-03-12 16:29:59
```

I would like to add a column called low2close
where from each row it takes the min(price) from the current time to the end of the day.  I have not figured out how to get variable loc window and run aggregate function (like min) on it.  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/generated/pandas.Series.cummin.html) after inversing the data with `[::-1]` (and reinversing the order after), all in `transform` after a `groupby` such as:

```
df['low2close'] = df.groupby('date')['price'].transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cummin()[::-1])
```

and it gives the min from the current row to the end of the day in a same date

```
            timestamp        date  price        endofdaytime  low2close
0 2018-03-11 13:03:00  2018-03-11  20.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52      19.00
1 2018-03-11 13:08:00  2018-03-11  19.00 2018-03-11 16:29:52      19.00
2 2018-03-11 15:22:00  2018-03-11  20.11 2018-03-11 16:29:52      20.03
3 2018-03-11 16:03:00  2018-03-11  21.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52      20.03
4 2018-03-11 16:29:52  2018-03-11  20.03 2018-03-11 16:29:52      20.03
5 2018-03-12 13:03:00  2018-03-12  20.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59      19.00
6 2018-03-12 13:08:00  2018-03-12  19.00 2018-03-12 16:29:59      19.00
7 2018-03-12 16:03:00  2018-03-12  21.03 2018-03-12 16:29:59      21.03
8 2018-03-12 16:29:59  2018-03-12  22.00 2018-03-12 16:29:59      22.00
```

Comment: Sweet - I'm in awe- Thanks